# Carthrob as an inquiry system

Tags: ecommerce

We're building a couple sites where our clients don't actually sell online but need everything else from an ecommerce tool. Users would add products to a cart, then submit the order to get an inquiry. We've been thinking on using carthrob so they can manage inventory and orders.

However, I can't find docs or examples of sites doing this. How can we checkout an inquiry order? And how would we deal with orders that have some products you can buy and others you need to inquiry for?

We can always do this with plain EE, but I still like using carthrob because it's important to create an order our clients could use. Should I just use SAEF instead?

Looking forward to hearing ideas!

Thanks in advance,

Santiago

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need CartThrob to do this. Try using something like Remember Me (a really nice free add-on) for creating "enquiry lists" and then Freeform or similar to do the "checkout" part and send an enquiry email to the site owner.

I guess it ultimately rests on what you mean by "an enquiry order". If you use Freeform then each enquiry becomes an entry within Freeform and you can set a status on it to show whether it has been actioned or not.

Or, as you say, you could use SAEF - which might actually be a much neater option come to think of it.

You said that your "clients don't actually sell online" and also ask how you would  "deal with orders that have some products you can buy and others you need to inquiry for?"

So do you need an ecommerce solution - i.e. so people can purchase items, or simply an enquiry system that lets your client mark enquiries with various statuses?

Comment: Thanks foamcow. They might start selling some items soon, so our concern is to make sure we're ready for an easy transition. They do have a Cartthrob license as well, bought before they hired our agency.

Comment: We'll probably go for SAEF, mainly to give them more flexibility and potentially integrating it with a helpdesk.

Comment: In that case I would go with SAEF and Remember Me to handle the enquiry stuff. Then you can add CartThrob later on if they start selling products.

Answer (score 2):

As Foamcow suggested to use "Remember Me" addon, yes it can work for it.

I think, you can achieve all those with CartThrob as CartThrob is already installed at your EE setup. There wouldn't be any payment system so you should use Offline Payment option with some more settings.

Now, make the checkout process as inquiry for orders. Also, you would like to have such a feature so that admin can see the items for which user inquired, and this can be done easily with the approach.
At CT checkout page, you can have a message field also for the user's message.